# Android OkHttp handling Oauth 2.0 Unauthorized (Http 401) and refreshing tokens

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, okhttp

I'm using OkHttpClient to consume Oauth 2.0 Api and all is fine using AppAuth Android library (https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android)..

All but using the OkHttp authenticator()..

Here's me instantiating the OkHttp Client:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .authenticator(new RefreshTokenAuthenticator())
```

Take note of the RefreshTokenAuthenticator class:

```
public class RefreshTokenAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
   @Nullable
    @Override
    public Request authenticate(@Nullable Route route, @NonNull okhttp3.Response response) {

            // And here I'm creating a TokenRequest based off the old refreshToken which I have already Stored in SharedPrefs..

            TokenRequest tokenRequest = new TokenRequest.Builder(
                    authServiceConfig,
                    CLIENT_ID
            )
                    .setAuthorizationCode(authorizationResponse.authorizationCode)
                    .setGrantType(GrantTypeValues.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                    .setRefreshToken(Utils.getRefreshToken_SP(ctx))
                    .build();

            // And trying to get new tokens asynchronously (as this seems to be the only method that I can use using the AppAuth-Android lib..

            new AuthorizationService(ctx).performTokenRequest(
                    tokenRequest,
                    new ClientSecretPost(API_AUTH_SECRET),
                    (tokenResponse, ex1) -> {
                        if (tokenResponse != null) {

                            // Got new tokens! But I'm in an asynchronous thread here :( Can't return to authenticate from this point..

                            Utils.writeAccessTokenToSharedPrefs(ctx, tokenResponse.accessToken);
                            Utils.writeRefreshToken_SP(ctx, tokenResponse.refreshToken);
                        }
                    });
            // Problem is that I need to fetch the token here (synchronously) so that I can apply the new "Authorization" Bearer to the request Headers and retry the api call.
    }
}
```

How to go about fetching the refresh tokens synchronously here?

Would love some feedback as I'm banging my head against the wall for a lot of hours here.
Maybe approach is wrong?!

I've tried using CountDownLatch / New Threads / AsyncTasks. Problem with each of these probably having to do with NetworkOnMainThread.

I'm a bit lost here. I saw some samples of some guys fetching the tokens form a Repository in another thread but I'm not sure how that's suppose to work.

Cheers!